Laser beam modulation by meander 455 kHz
I need to modulate a laser beam with a 455 kHz square wave. I have assembled a square wave generator and have a green laser diode with a power of 15 mW. I do not know what to do next. I want to observe the square wave from the laser diode at a frequency of 455 kHz on an oscilloscope with a connected photodiode. The maximum threshold current is 150 mA. FM modulation is needed.

What are your expectations? (values)

Are you wanting to amplitude modulate the intensity of the beam?  Or deflect the beam? Or FM modulate?

Look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518472/a-laser-driver-mld203p1-with-an-external-bias-tee-for-modulation

FYI: Power is measure in Watt, not Volt. I corrected your text to say 15 mW (not 15mV).

Yes, thanks for the correction. Mechanical error.

D Duck:
FM modulation is needed.

D.A.S. :
I expect to see a meander on the oscilloscope with a connected photodiode

Davud I am looking for Laser specs on FM deviation for 525 nm when you applied 455 kHz AM with a low modulation index. Does that make sense? like 1 Ghz/ mA converted to nm

Meander means sqare wave???

Yes Fred, you are right.

D.A.S: The thing is that I haven't decided on the connection scheme yet. There is very little information on this issue on the Internet and I am a newbie in this area. That's why it's hard for me to come up with a connection scheme. I even assembled a scheme on OPA357 from the datasheet but couldn't achieve the result.

No, a meander is a curvy path like that ofa river takes, while a square wave is a type of orthogonal waveform

meander and rectangular signal are almost the same thing, only meander differs in the pulse duration, in my case we are talking about rectangular signal.

@DavudAgazade - I don't think you're using the word "meander" correctly... in the context of electronics, people will likely interpret this as "the wiggles added to a trace on a PCB for length matching purposes"... I've certainly never heard of "seeing a meander on a scope", and searching for "meander generator" gives no promising results. Is this a translation issue perhaps?

... "Wt" is also not a unit I'm familiar with did you means Watts (i.e: "W")

"Meander is a Greek ornament, which is a border made up of straight continuous lines that form right angles between themselves." A meander is a meander. At your request, I edited the question.
